# How would we count the number of times the program calls the put() and get() functions?

Tags: java

Suppose we are using a map in our program, how would we count the number of times the program calls the put() and get() functions? .
What if we created multiple instances of the map? How would you sum up the total count for each map object? Actually a friend told me that he got this question in his java job interview. I found solutions but I didn't get it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add the calls to methods in a class, use an `static` field:

```
public class Map ... {
    private static int count = 0;

    public ... get(...) {
        count++;
        ...
    }

    public void put(...) {
        count++;
        ...
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: so we keep the count variables static. Thank you

Comment: Note that a static variable would yield incorrect values if you had more than one instance of the map and were interested in per-instance counts.  It seems an instance variable would be a better approach.

Comment: This is for the case you want to sum up all instances calls.

Comment: so the static variables have only one copy for all objects of class so the total count would be reflected in count variables .Do I got it clear ? or this is wrong

Comment: Yes, an static member is a 'class' member, not an 'instance' member.

Comment: If you are using the builtin `Map<K,V>` class you can't do this, you must extend the class so you can override `get()` and `put()`... or you could use bytecode instrumentation to intercept those method calls, but that's much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, assuming that it is okay for the program to use a subclass of Map rather than a standard Java Map:

```
public class MyMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
    int getCount = 0;

     @override
     public V get(K key) {
          getCount++;
          return super.get(key);
     }

     public getGetCount() {
         return getCount;
     }
}
```

It is also worth noting that mocking frameworks solve a similar problem (although this particular problem is just one small thing that they do).  Mockito for example produces mock versions of classes/interfaces that count the number of invocations of each method. The mocks themselves are not immediately usable unless you implement some stubbing behaviors.  Or if you use a mockito, spy, that is similar to inheritance and might be the fastest way to achieve this behavior.  See https://code.google.com/p/mockito/ for more info.

Comment: so we put count variable for get() here ? this what the called it increment the count ? Thank you for the approach.

Comment: Thank you also @Ejk for your Explanation .